# Angular 2 Tour of Heroes HeroService rxjs operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

Following along with the angular.io http documentation, if we have the following (observable) HeroService:

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
}
```

Then, we subscribe to the returned Observable at the component level:

```
getHeroes() {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
                   .subscribe(
                     heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                     error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Are we able to use rxjs observable operators at the component level? I'm interested in using the filters to further refine (and re-use) the same http get. I tried the code snippet below, but obviously the operator fails because the HeroService returns `Observable<Hero[]>` and the filter needs `Observable<Hero>`. Can I use flatmap and reconstruct the array?

```
getHeroes() {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
                  .filter(h => h.id > 10)
                  .subscribe(
                     heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                     error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Why not just filter the received array? `.subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.filter(h => h.id > 10), ...`. Seems much simpler to me.

Comment: You could also potentially use something like `getHeroes().map(h => h.filter(i => i.id > 10))` and store that observable as a variable. Then I believe you can just subscribe to it each time you want to call the API and have that filter (map) applied. I'm pretty sure calling subscribe on the HTTP observable will call the API each time.

Comment: Functionally, is filtering within the subscribe function any different? Two-way data binding and such would still work?

Comment: The question was around the idea of being able to create an `Observable` that could be re-called later on and return the desired data, which is possible and might be desirable if you're going for pure reactive style programming. But yes, there's no reason you couldn't just filter within the subscribe.

Comment: I see exactly what you mean. Thank you both!